# Single-threaded app with multiple vCPUs?

Tags: node.js, cpu, vcpu

As I learned from different websites like [this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1234.hyper-v-concepts-vcpu-virtual-processor-q-a.aspx#Virtual_cores), vCPU represents a portion of time of a physical CPU core(s) that is assigned to a VM, where some process is running. And also:

> As threads execute (vCPUs are used) they are cycled around the
>   physical CPUs.

Does that mean that if I assign more vCPUs to my VM then my app (node.js) thread will be able to use all of this vCPUs and run faster despite that node.js is single-threaded?

p.s. If I picked the wrong place (forum) to ask this question please tell me the forum where I can get an answer.

Comment: The only benefit you'll get from multiple processors will come from having a separate one for syscalls. You can use the cluster module to run multiple threads with the same script to take advantage of multiple processors. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/cluster.html

Comment: But what about the info on the website that linked? And the fact that this vCPUs will most probably reside on a single core, and a single core can fully process single thread? One core (without hyperthreading) is only capable of processing one thread, so that's probably exactly what I need.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: vCPU in what context? AWS, Azure or another technology? If it's AWS, this should answer your question (2nd half): https://stackoverflow.com/a/77380859/4800344